# how to make the text of a bound checkbox list a link to a file?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a checkbox list that is bound to a data source. The data is a list of strings that represent file paths. I want the value to be the file path and the label to be a link to the file. Is this possible? TIA!

Comment: Use a repeater with a custom `UserControl` consisting of your controls instead.

Comment: I'm new at this. Could you give me an example of how I could do this?

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that the text field for each checkbox is surrounded with a link tag: `<a href..>`.

So for example, you might have a datasource like the following:

```
Dictionary<string, string> links = new Dictionary<string, string>();

links.Add("<a href='/filepath1'>somefile</a>", "filepath1");
links.Add("<a href='/filepath2'>somefile2</a>", "filepath2");

CheckBoxList1.DataSource = links;
CheckBoxList1.DataTextField = "Key";
CheckBoxList1.DataValueField = "Value";
CheckBoxList1.DataBind();
```

Hope this helps (although not very elegant)